# How to find a child is defined or not in php class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I get a POST data by this code.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
```

Then I want to get a data.

```
$form->get('send')->isChecked();
```

If there is a 'send' submit button, it works well,however there is not it show this error.

```
Child "send" does not exist.
```

Then I have struggled to see if 'send' data is included $form or not.

like this

```
if ($form->get('send') !== null){
```

However it shows the same error.

How can I tell there is 'send' submit button in $form ??

---

There is 'send' button or 'draft' button depending on the situation.

I would like to tell which button is exist.

```
if ($form->get('send')->isChecked()){
} 
else if( $form->get('draft')->isChecked()){
}
```

but ,this code shows the error when access the button which is not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Symphony and, after looking at their terrible documentation, I probably will never. Based on looking at the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php), the `$form` object should have a `has($name)` method. So try

```
if ($form->has('send')){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
<input type='submit' name='send' value='go' />
```

in your form. it will solve this problem.

Comment: I know it can slove the problem,but what in my program, sometimes there is 'send' form,sometimes not(there is draft button instead of). it depends on the situation. I don't want to show the error message